# How do I use a Dialog Form to open another form and filter a query

Tags: database, forms, ms-access

**What I have**

I have a Query called **qryFlightPrices**.
I have a form which is based on this Query called **frmFlightPrices**.
I have a Dialog Form called **dlgfrmFilterFlightPrices**.

The dialog form contains two text boxes called Price and Departure and a command button called Open Form.

**What I want to do**

I want the command button on the dialog form to open the form called **frmFlightPrices** and then for this form to run a filter which is based on what is entered in the text boxes on the dialog form.

**What I have done so far**

In the Filter property of the form **frmFlightPrices** I entered 
**Price > Forms![frmFlightPrices]![txtPrice]** and set the Filter OnLoad property to yes.

**The Problem**

However when I enter the Price criteria and press the Command Button on the Dialog Form one of two things happen:

either

a)an Access Dialog Box opens and asks me to enter the criteria again

OR

b) the form opens but there are no records

Can anyone explain why this Access system dialog box opens and why do my records appear blank.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dialog form `dlgfrmFilterFlightPrices` is not referenced by form `frmFlightPrices`. The `Filter` property should be:

```
    Price > Forms![dlgfrmFilterFlightPrices]![Price]
```

Note that `dlgfrmFilterFlightPrices` **must** be open for `frmFlightPrices.Filter` to work.